# Box Api Upload or download

Tags: curl, box-api

How do I convert this code to download and upload using the Box Api to C#

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/content \
-H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=API_KEY&auth_token=AUTH_TOKEN" \
-F filename=@FILE_NAME \
-F folder_id=FOLDER_ID
```

I want to convert this cURL to c# using WebRequest

Comment: There is a v2 C# SDK that will do this for you.  You can build it from [source](https://github.com/jhoerr/box-csharp-sdk-v2) or use the [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/box.v2.sdk) package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I defer to John Hoerr's answer in the comment above.